# Why is the runtime of the selection algorithm O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, selection, big-o

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm), partition-based selection algorithms such as quickselect have runtime of `O(n)`, but I am not convinced by it. Can anyone explain why it is `O(n)`?

In the normal quick-sort, the runtime is `O(n log n)`. Every time we partition the branch into two branches (greater than the pivot and lesser than the pivot), we need to continue the process in **both** branches, whereas quickselect only needs to process **one** branch. I totally understand these points. 
However, if you think in the Binary Search algorithm, after we chose the middle element, we are also searching only **one** side of the branch. So does that make the algorithm `O(1)`? *No*, of course, the Binary Search Algorithm is still `O(log N)` instead of `O(1)`. This is also the same thing as the search element in a Binary Search Tree. We only search for **one** side, but we still consider `O(log n)` instead of `O(1)`.

Can someone explain why in quickselect, if we continue the search in *one* side of pivot, it is considered `O(1)` instead of `O(log n)`? I consider the algorithm to be `O(n log n)`, `O(N)` for the partitioning, and `O(log n)` for the number of times to continue finding.

Comment: Because `O(N) + O(log N) = O(N)`. When you do something and then do something else, you *sum* the orders, not multiply them.

Comment: The Wikipedia page you link to is about selection algorithms in general and it mentions many of them. Some of them are O(n) while some are not ; which one are you talking about ? Also, why would you compare the quicksort algorithm with a selection algorithm ? They serve different purpose. Maybe you are confusing selection algorithms with the [selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Selection_sort) ?

Comment: It is not do something and then do something. If I understand correctly, it is that each of O(logn) you do O(n) to partition into two sides.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz- The OP's question is why, if you need to do O(log N) iterations of the partition step, each of which takes O(N), it doesn't take a total of O(N log N)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

There are several different selection algorithms, from the much simpler quickselect (expected O(n), worst-case O(n<sup>2</sup>)) to the more complex median-of-medians algorithm (Θ(n)).  Both of these algorithms work by using a quicksort partitioning step (time O(n)) to rearrange the elements and position one element into its proper position.  If that element is at the index in question, we're done and can just return that element.  Otherwise, we determine which side to recurse on and recurse there.

Let's now make a very strong assumption - suppose that we're using quickselect (pick the pivot randomly) and on each iteration we manage to guess the exact middle of the array.  In that case, our algorithm will work like this: we do a partition step, throw away half of the array, then recursively process one half of the array.  This means that on each recursive call we end up doing work proportional to the length of the array at that level, but that length keeps decreasing by a factor of two on each iteration.  If we work out the math (ignoring constant factors, etc.) we end up getting the following time:

- Work at the first level: n
- Work after one recursive call: n / 2
- Work after two recursive calls: n / 4
- Work after three recursive calls: n / 8
- ...

This means that the total work done is given by

> n + n / 2 + n / 4 + n / 8 + n / 16 + ... = n (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...)

Notice that this last term is n times the sum of 1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, etc.  If you work out this infinite sum, despite the fact that there are infinitely many terms, the total sum is exactly 2.  This means that the total work is

> n + n / 2 + n / 4 + n / 8 + n / 16 + ... = n (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...) = 2n

This may seem weird, but the idea is that if we do linear work on each level but keep cutting the array in half, we end up doing only roughly 2n work.

An important detail here is that there are indeed O(log n) different iterations here, but not all of them are doing an equal amount of work.  Indeed, each iteration does half as much work as the previous iteration.  If we ignore the fact that the work is decreasing, you can conclude that the work is O(n log n), which is correct but not a tight bound.  This more precise analysis, which uses the fact that the work done keeps decreasing on each iteration, gives the O(n) runtime.

Of course, this is a very optimistic assumption - we almost never get a 50/50 split! - but using a more powerful version of this analysis, you can say that if you can guarantee *any* constant factor split, the total work done is only some constant multiple of n.  If we pick a totally random element on each iteration (as we do in quickselect), then on expectation we only need to pick two elements before we end up picking some pivot element in the middle 50% of the array, which means that, on expectation, only two rounds of picking a pivot are required before we end up picking something that gives a 25/75 split.  This is where the expected runtime of O(n) for quickselect comes from.

A formal analysis of the median-of-medians algorithm is much harder because the recurrence is difficult and not easy to analyze.  Intuitively, the algorithm works by doing a small amount of work to guarantee a good pivot is chosen.  However, because there are two different recursive calls made, an analysis like the above won't work correctly.  You can either use an advanced result called the [Akra-Bazzi theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method), or use the formal definition of big-O to explicitly prove that the runtime is O(n).  For a more detailed analysis, check out "Introduction to Algorithms, Third Edition" by Cormen, Leisserson, Rivest, and Stein.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If we make assumption that we always make 50/50 split. That should give us O(nlogn), this is mentioned in the wikipedia page: "Note the resemblance to quicksort: just as the minimum-based selection algorithm is a partial selection sort, this is a partial quicksort, generating and partitioning only O(log n) of its O(n) partitions". You may search for these words in the wikipedia.

Comment: @user926958- While you are correct that there are O(log n) iterations, not all iterations are doing the same amount of work, and in fact each iteration is doing half as much work as before.  It's for this reason that a total of O(log n) iterations doesn't give rise to an O(n log n) runtime, since each of those iterations is doing substantially less work than the previous iteration.  Summing up the total work being done across the iterations, rather than counting the number of iterations and multiplying by the maximum work each one does, gives the O(n) answer.  Does this make sense?

Comment: I've posted a detailed average case analysis - without the assumption of a constant factor split - as answer on a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25796762/1849515. The answer here of course gives a better intuition than the mathematical analysis.

Comment: Going off the simpler quick select, shouldn't big oh just be O(n<sup>2</sup>), not O(n)? The definition of big Oh should be worst case. Anyone know to fix the sup html tag so that it produces the exponent?

Comment: @committedandroider It's correct to say that on expectation the runtime is O(n) and that in the worst case it's O(n^2) since the average case complexity and worst-case complexity are different. Big-O doesn't necessarily refer to the worst case; you can use it to talk about all sorts of different things.

Comment: Can u explain if ur analysis is correct then why is it O(n) and not O(logn) shouldn't it ur series be multiplied by log n? There are log n iterations and layers so why not (log n(n+n/2+n/4... Etc)?

Comment: @bilanush Imagine that I have a loop that runs n times and does 1 unit of work on each iteration. One way I could compute the total work would be to multiply the number of loop iterations (n) by the work done per iteration (1) to get n * 1 = O(n) total work. Another would be to add up the work done on each iteration to get 1 + 1 + 1 + ... + 1 = n, since there are n iterations that each do 1 unit of work. However, it would not be correct to combine these techniques and to compute n * (1 + 1 + 1 + ... + 1) = n^2, since that would multiply the total work done by the number of loop iterations.

Comment: "If we pick a totally random element on each iteration (as we do in quickselect), then on expectation we only need to pick two elements before we end up picking some pivot element in the middle 50% of the array, which means that, on expectation, only two rounds of picking a pivot are required before we end up picking something that gives a 25/75 split."  What does "middle 50% of the array" mean? I don't understand how you have come to the conclusion that picking 2 elements is enough to get a 25/75 split.

Comment: Thanks for asking. By “middle 50%,” I meant an element whose value is between the 25th and 75th percentiles for all values. If you pick pivots randomly, you certainly aren’t guaranteed to hit something in that range in two tries, but since you have a 50% chance on each pivot choice, the expected number of probes will be 2 before you find something there. (This follows from the fact that the mean of a geometrically distributed variable with probability p is 1/p).

Answer (score 20):

Let me try to explain the difference between selection & binary search.

Binary search algorithm in each step does O(1) operations. Totally there are log(N) steps and this makes it O(log(N))

Selection algorithm in each step performs O(n) operations. But this 'n' keeps on reducing by half each time. There are totally log(N) steps.
This makes it N + N/2 + N/4 + ... + 1 (log(N) times) = 2N = O(N)

For binary search it is 1 + 1 + ... (log(N) times) = O(logN)

Comment: N + N/2 + N/4 + ... + 1 (log(N) times) should equal to O(NlogN). Your (N + N/2 + N/4 + ... + 1) will roughly equal to 2N, so 2N * (logN times) is O(NlogN)

Comment: @user926958- Actually, that sum is equal to 2N by using the formula for the sum of an infinite geometric series.  This is the reason why the total work done is O(N).  The sum N + N + ... + N O(log N) times is indeed O(N log N), though.

Comment: @user926958 "N + N/2 + N/4 + ... + 1 (log(N) times) should equal to O(NlogN)" is wrong because it is a geometric sequence instead of an arithmetic sequence . So it should be about 2N.

Answer (score 3):

In Quicksort, the recursion tree is lg(N) levels deep and each of these levels requires O(N) amount of work. So the total running time is O(NlgN).

In Quickselect, the recurision tree is lg(N) levels deep and each level requires only half the work of the level above it. This produces the following:

```
N * (1/1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...)
```

or

```
N * Summation(1/i^2)
    1 < i <= lgN
```

The important thing to note here is that i goes from 1 to lgN, but not from 1 to N and also not from 1 to infinity.

The summation evaluates to 2. Hence Quickselect = O(2N).

Answer (score 1):

Quicksort does not have a big-O of nlogn - it's worst case runtime is n^2.

I assume you're asking about Hoare's Selection Algorithm (or quickselect) not the naive selection algorithm that is O(kn). Like quicksort, quickselect has a worst case runtime of O(n^2) (if bad pivots are chosen), not O(n). It can run in expectation time n because it's only sorting one side, as you point out.

Comment: However, there are algorithms (namely, the median-of-medians algorithm) that *do* run in worst-case O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

Because for selection, you're not sorting, necessarily. You can simply count how many items there are which have any given value. So an O(n) median can be performed by counting how many times each value comes up, and picking the value that has 50% of items above and below it. It's 1 pass through the array, simply incrementing a counter for each element in the array, so it's O(n).

For example, if you have an array "a" of 8 bit numbers, you can do the following:

```
int histogram [ 256 ];
for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    histogram [ i ] = 0;
}
for (i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
{
    histogram [ a [ i ] ]++;
}
i = 0;
sum = 0;
while (sum < (numItems / 2))
{
    sum += histogram [ i ];
    i++;
}
```

At the end, the variable "i" will contain the 8-bit value of the median. It was about 1.5 passes through the array "a". Once through the entire array to count the values, and half through it again to get the final value.